# How reading strings not encoded in utf-8 in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string, utf-8

in my application I have 6 SQL INSERT strings containing text data in German, French, Spanish, English, Russian and Italian. I obtain the SQL string using SQLiteStudio (running on a 64 bits Win 7 o.s.) from a filled table. This is the German string:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# \file deHelpData.py 
# \brief
#
# \version rel. 1.0
# \date Created on 2023-05-08
# \author massimo
# Copyryght (C) 2023 organization_name. All rights reserved.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: windows-1252

deHelpQryStr = str(''' 
    INSERT INTO deHelp (
           text,
           tag,
           id
       )
       VALUES (
           'Dies ist die Anleitung der Emuse -App. Klicken Sie auf die Schaltfläche Links, um auf die Schaltfläche zur Hauptseite zurückzukehren, um die Sprachreproduktion zu suspendieren oder fortzusetzen. Klicken Sie auf die rechte Schaltfläche. Die Emuse -App besteht aus 5 Seiten, jeweils ihren eigenen Titel oben sichtbar. Diese Version, die für das Gramsci Birthplace Museum in Ales angepasst wurde, umfasst die Funktionen von Audioguida, gleichzeitige Übersetzung, Navigation und Hilfe. Alle Funktionen sind im Hauptmenü zugänglich, indem Sie auf die jeweilige Schaltfläche klicken. Die Real -Time -Übersetzungsfunktion ist nur aktiv, indem sie sich im und in der Nähe des Museums befinden, während die anderen Funktionen immer aktiv sind. Wenn Sie oben auf die erste Schaltfläche klicken, greifen Sie auf die Funktion des Audiohandbuchs zu, die die Kamera aktiviert. Im Museum wurden QR -Codes in der Nähe der Interessenspunkte ähnlich wie beim Herunterladen der App gescannt. Durch die Rahmung eines QR -Codes wird die Reproduktion des Audios in Bezug auf die Arbeit, auf die sie sich bezieht, aktiviert. Wenn Sie auf die zweite Schaltfläche klicken, überfahren Sie in Echtzeit zur Seite der Vokalübersetzungsfunktion. Wenn Sie auf die Schaltfläche links klicken, wählen Sie hier Ihre Zunge aus und klicken Sie kurz auf die zentrale Rolle. Übersetzen. Die Sprache, in der Sie übersetzen möchten, ist immer italienisch. Die Audio -Reproduktion in der übersetzten Sprache beginnt, wenn sie zum Sprechen endet. Für eine gute Operation der Übersetzung ist es notwendig, ohne lange Unterbrechungen zwischen den Wörtern oder den nachfolgenden Sätzen zu sprechen. Im Hauptmenü wird durch Klicken auf die dritte Schaltfläche die Navigationsfunktion aktiviert. Das Ziel ist mit den Koordinaten des Museums voreingestellt. Wenn Sie auf die zentrale Schaltfläche klicken, beginnt die Navigation. Indem Sie kurz auf das grüne Signal klicken, werden die Koordinaten und die ungefähre Adresse dessen, wo Sie sich befinden, angezeigt. Indem Sie kurz auf das rote Signal klicken, erscheinen die Koordinaten und die Adresse des Museums. Wenn Sie lange auf das rote Zeichen klicken, werden die grundlegenden Informationen des Museums angezeigt. Mit dem Navigator können Sie die beste Route zwischen der Position, in der Sie sich befinden, und dem Museum berechnen, indem Sie die Transportmittel zwischen Auto, Fahrrad zu Fuß und für die behinderten Rollstühle auswählen. Wenn Sie mit dem Fragepunkt auf die letzte Schaltfläche klicken, wird dieser Text angezeigt, der ebenfalls gelesen wird. Klicken Sie links auf die Schaltfläche, um das Lesen oder auf die rechts auf die Seite zu beenden, um die Seite zu beenden.',
           'help',
           1
       ),
       (
           'Die Emuse unterstützt nicht die Sprache auf Ihrem Smartphone. Bitte wählen Sie eine der unterstützten Sprachen, indem Sie auf die entsprechende Schaltfläche klicken.',
           'lang',
           2
       ),
       (
           'Wählen Sie die Sprache, in der Sie Ihre Stimme übersetzen möchten, indem Sie auf die entsprechende Schaltfläche klicken.',
           'langTo',
           3
       ),
       (
           'Willkommen in Emide. Wenn Sie die App zum ersten Mal verwenden, empfehle ich Ihnen, mit dem Fragestalk auf die Schaltfläche zu klicken, die Ihnen bei der ersten Verwendung hilft. Wenn Sie andererseits die App bereits kennen, um die Audiohandbuch zu verwenden, klicken Sie auf die erste Schaltfläche oben, für den gleichzeitigen Übersetzer im zweiten, für den Navigator auf dem dritten.',
           'main',
           4
       ),
       (
           'Audioguide',
           'guideTitle',
           5
       ),
       (
           'Hilfe',
           'helpTitle',
           6
       ),
       (
           'Hauptmenü',
           'mainTitle',
           7
       ),
       (
           'Navigator',
           'navigatorTitle',
           8
       ),
       (
           'Übersetzer',
           'translatorTitle',
           9
       );
    ''', "cp1252")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but when the Python interpreter loads the string produces this error:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 178: invalid continuation byte

What have I to do to use correctly this string?
Thanks,
Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `# encoding: windows-1252` declares the encoding of the *source file* and must be the first or second line of the file (Refer [PEP 263 - Defining Python Source Encodings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/)).  The file must actually be saved in Windows-1252 to match the declaration.  Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 encoding, which is the default encoding expected for Python 3 source files, and remove the `# encoding` line.

Additionally, the `#!/usr/bin/python` line should be the first line in the file to be effective.

There is no need for `str(..., encoding='cp1252')`.  That would normally convert a byte string encoded in Windows-1252 into a Unicode string, but your string is already a Unicode string.

Comment: Likewise, if the source code is Windows-1252, the database tables need to use a character set of `latin1` and the collation should be set to `latin1_german1_ci` or `latin1_german2_ci`.

Comment: @Andj The source code encoding declaration only affects the interpretation of bytes in literal Unicode strings in the source file. The encoding used by sockets, files, databases, etc. can be different. Also Windows-1252 has differences from Latin1 encoding.

Comment: my point was simply that everything needs to be the same encoding, source data, database tables, source code, etc. Yes ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 are different encodings and Latin-1 is an alias for ISO-8859-1, but not always. For databases, they speak of character sets and collations, although character set is probably not the most accurate label for what is meant. And sqlite has the most primitive approach to collation of most RDBMS. If you add web into the mix then iso-8859-1 is treated as an alias of Windows-1252 rather than a separate encoding, as do some other databases.